# WPF Drag and Drop DragDropEffects changing when moving off of WPF Window

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I have a WPF application where I'm dragging an file object around. It can be dropped either into several windows inside of the application, or externally into Explorer and onto the desktop and a few other places.

The drag and drop operation works fine, but the DragDropEffect only shows properly inside of the application Window. When the cursor moves outside of the App window I get the 'verboten' icon - most of the time. Depending on how the cursor leaves the app most of the time I get the slashed out circle. But sometimes it correctly continues dragging with the copy icon.

```
var files = new[] {editor.MarkdownDocument.Filename} ;
var dragData = new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop,files);

DragDrop.DoDragDrop(tab, dragData, DragDropEffects.Copy);
```

As mentioned the code and the handling by the shell works properly - the file is copied, it's only the drag icon that's the problem.

I can control the drag icon inside of the application, no problem on the window, but I have no control what happens outside of it.

So how do I control the drag icon reliably external to WPF?

Comment: Could it be related to UAC? Two apps on different UAC level can't talk. So it you run you WPF app as admin, and your explorer is restricted (the default), D&D won't work.

Comment: Not in this case - everything is running in user mode. I have noticed though that Windows is doing strange stuff with drag and drop *everywhere* in a few cases not properly showing the drag icon. Not quite the same. Rebooted and now see more *differerent* weird stuff. Wondering now if there might be an issue with Windows itself that's causing all this.

Comment: Maybe some 3rd party software is playing weird with the Shell? I'd check what .dlls are loaded into explorer.exe (with sysinternals' procexp or autoruns tools for example)

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dragdrop.givefeedback

```
DragDrop.GiveFeedback += SetTheCursorHere;
```

You should (per Microsoft's documentation) cache the cursor, etc. because it's called over and over again while dragging, and you don't want to LoadResource as the drag occurs.

Comment: I've looked at this and it looks like GiveFeedback is the only even that fires outside of the WPF window. But while I can set the *Mouse Cursor* I can't change the *Drag Cursor* (e.Effects is readonly). When I set `UseDefaultCursors = false` and then assign an explicit Mouse cursor I get dual cursors that overlay and they flash like crazy (would at least need to throttle).